# llvm: cast i8* type value to double type value

Tags: c++, llvm

I have a char pointer (Type::getInt8PtrTy(Context) ) and trying to convert a value (string in other words) which holds this pointer into double type (Type::getDoubleTy(Context)). The way I tried is:

```
Value* stringValue = ... // Value which type Type::getInt8PtrTy(Context)
auto doubleValue = CastInst::CreatePointerCast(stringValue, Type::getDoubleTy(Context), Builder.GetInsertBlock());
AllocaInst *alloca = .. //alloc memory for element which type is Type::getDoubleTy(Context)
Builder.CreateStore(doubleValue, alloca);
```

The problem is when I'm trying to print doubleValue using external C function (printf), looks like that I got the address but not double value. In other words, I want to write code which do the same like C atoi function.
I'm using C++ API.

I would be grateful for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

`atoi` doesn't simply cast a variable to a different type. It actually converts a string value into an integer by means of some algorithm.

If you want to do the same, you'll have to include a function implementing that algorithm in your bitcode and then use `call` instruction on your pointer to get the `double` value.

If you really want to interpret string's data as double, use `bitcast` to cast the pointer from `i8*` to `double*` and then use `load` instruction.